# How to assign different ID to dynamically created HTML form elements inside a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 4) {        
  $('#container').append("<div><input type='textbox' class ='left'/><input type='textbox' class ='right' /></div>");
    i = i + 1;
  }
```

**I need different ID's for the above created input textbox so that I can access their value.**

Comment: concatenate your string with `i` variable. What have you tried??? BTW, do you really need IDs? Usually in most cases, you don't

Comment: Ayush, my friend, this is what `for` loops were made for! `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { ... }`

Comment: I tried string concatenatoin but this thing in above code didn't work.
<input type='textbox' id=" 'left' + i " />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong, based on what you attempted in your comment.
Try this:

```
  for (i=0; i<4; i++) {        
  $('#container').append("<div><input type='textbox' class ='left'/><input type='textbox' class ='right' id='left"+ i +"' /></div>");
  }
```

That will declare your counter, increment your counter, and append your container, setting the ID correctly on the way.